# Formik Field Array field's id change when wrap with modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamics-crm, formik, chakra-ui

I'm using Formik with chakra UI to create dynamic forms using the Fomrik Field array. and I Open my form in [Chakra modal](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/overlay/modal), problem is when I open my form in modal it change field name and id to array last object id , When i remove modal its works as expected, **I Recreated my problem** [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-chakra-ui-forked-vftld)

my code sample

```
 <Box>
    {/* start card grid */}
    <Box py="12" px={{ base: "6", md: "0" }}>
      <FormikProvider value={formik}>
        <Box as="section" maxW={{ base: "xs", md: "full" }} mx="auto">

              <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <SimpleGrid
                  columns={{ base: 1, sm: 1, md: 3, xl: 4 }}
                  spacing="6"
                >
                  
                  <FieldArray name="locations">
                    
                    {() =>
                      formik.values?.locations?.map(
                        (props: any, index: string) => {
                          const { location, reviews } = props;
                          return (
                            <>
                            <Modal
                                  isOpen={isOpen}
                                  onClose={onClose}
                                
                                >
                                  <ModalOverlay />
                                  <ModalContent>
                                    <ModalCloseButton />
                                    <ModalBody >
                                      <>
                                        <FormLabel>Page URL</FormLabel>
                                        <InputGroup size="md">
                                          <InputLeftAddon
                                            borderTopEndRadius={0}
                                            borderBottomEndRadius={0}
                                            borderColor="grayExtend.300"
                                            bg="grayExtend.100"
                                            fontSize="0.8rem"
                                            px={2}
                                          >
                                            {modal.urlPrefix}
                                          </InputLeftAddon>
                                            <>
                                              <Input
                                                name={`locations.${index}.facebookUrl`}
                                                value={
                                                  formik.values.locations[
                                                    index
                                                  ].facebookUrl
                                                }
                                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                                placeholder="facebook name"
                                                type="text"
                                                borderWidth="1.5px"
                                                fontSize="0.8rem"
                                                borderColor="grayExtend.300"
                                                borderTopStartRadius={0}
                                                borderBottomStartRadius={
                                                  0
                                                }
                                              />
                                              <Box
                                                fontSize="0.875rem"
                                                color="red"
                                                mt={2}
                                              >                                                      
                                          </Box>
                                          </>
                                        </InputGroup>
                                      </>
                                    </ModalBody>
                                    <ModalFooter mb={4}>
                                      <Button
                                        key={`btn${
                                          Math.random() * 1000
                                        }`}
                                        id={modal.web}
                                        colorScheme="blue"
                                        border="1px"
                                        isFullWidth
                                        type="submit"
                                        _hover={{ bg: "#152aa3" }}
                                        disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                                      >
                                        Submit
                                      </Button>
                                    </ModalFooter>
                                  </ModalContent>
                                </Modal>
                              <Flex
                                direction="column"
                                alignItems="center"
                                rounded="md"
                                padding="8"
                                position="relative"
                                shadow="base"
                                id={index}
                              >
                                <Box
                                  position="absolute"
                                  inset="0"
                                  height="20"
                                  roundedTop="inherit"
                                />                                       
                                <VStack
                                  spacing="4"
                                  mt={3}
                                >
                                  {buttons.map(
                                    ({ title, id, icon }) => (
                                      <Button
                                      key={id+1}
                                        id={id}
                                        colorScheme="grayExtend.100"
                                        borderWidth="1px"
                                        borderColor="grayExtend.300"
                                        variant="outline"
                                        p="10px"
                                        borderRadius="4px"
                                        minH="60px"
                                        minW="300px"
                                        onClick={(e) =>
                                          handleOpenModal(e)
                                        }
                                        className={
                                          formik.values.locations[index]
                                            .facebookUrl &&
                                            formik.errors &&
                                            formik.errors.locations &&
                                          getIn(
                                            formik.errors,
                                            `locations.${index}.facebookUrl`
                                          ) &&
                                          "success"
                                        }
                                        display="flex"
                                        justifyContent="start"
                                        bg="#f5faff"
                                        fontSize="0.875rem"
                                      >
                                        {title}
                                      </Button>
                                    )
                                  )}
                                </VStack>
                              
                              </Flex>
                            </>
                          );
                        }
                      )
                    }
                  </FieldArray>
                </SimpleGrid>
              </form>

        </Box>
      </FormikProvider>
    </Box>
    {/* end card grid */}
  </Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

as I can see you create modal views for each field. This is not a bad solution but it is better to make one modal and give it data to display (I take out the modal component from the map cycle)

Now the main problem to set special data for each button. I add the state new field **id**.

In formik inputs change values and names to **locations[${modal.id}].facebookUrl**

The reason, why are you getting last modal **is not controlling it's statement**. There is now field which says React not to show 2nd,3nd or other components, so there are 4 modals on each other. You can also use your code but add condition which will hide or show your modal view for example
`modal.id === idx && <Modal/>`

Also [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/formik-chakra-ui-forked-3qvsl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) of this code

```js
import {
  Box,
  useDisclosure,
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalCloseButton,
  ModalContent,
  ModalOverlay,
  SimpleGrid,
  Flex,
  VStack,
  FormLabel,
  Input,
  InputGroup,
  InputLeftAddon,
  ModalFooter
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { FieldArray, getIn, useFormik, FormikProvider } from "formik";

import * as React from "react";

const Form = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = React.useState({
    web: "",
    urlPrefix: "",
    id: 0
  });

  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  const cardData: any = {
    locations: [
      {
        facebookUrl: "fb 1"
      },
      {
        facebookUrl: "fb2"
      },
      {
        facebookUrl: ""
      },
      {
        facebookUrl: ""
      }
    ]
  };

  const buttons = [
    {
      id: "facebook",
      title: "Facebook",
      icon: ""
    }
  ];

  // modal func
  const handleOpenModal = (e: any, idx: number) => {
    const { id } = e.target;
    if (id === "facebook") {
      setModal({
        ...modal,
        web: "facebook",
        urlPrefix: "facebook.com",
        id: idx
      });
    } else return null;
    onOpen();
    return null;
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: cardData,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }
  });
  return (
    <Box>
      {/* start card grid */}
      <Box py="12" px={{ base: "6", md: "0" }}>
        <FormikProvider value={formik}>
          <Box as="section" maxW={{ base: "xs", md: "full" }} mx="auto">
            <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
              <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
                <ModalOverlay />
                <ModalContent>
                  <ModalCloseButton />
                  <ModalBody>
                    <>
                      <FormLabel>Page URL</FormLabel>
                      <InputGroup size="md">
                        <InputLeftAddon
                          borderTopEndRadius={0}
                          borderBottomEndRadius={0}
                          borderColor="grayExtend.300"
                          bg="grayExtend.100"
                          fontSize="0.8rem"
                          px={2}
                        >
                          {modal.urlPrefix}
                        </InputLeftAddon>
                        <>
                          <Input
                            name={`locations[${modal.id}].facebookUrl`}
                            value={
                              formik.values.locations[modal.id].facebookUrl
                            }
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                            placeholder="facebook name"
                            type="text"
                            borderWidth="1.5px"
                            fontSize="0.8rem"
                            borderColor="grayExtend.300"
                            borderTopStartRadius={0}
                            borderBottomStartRadius={0}
                          />
                          <Box fontSize="0.875rem" color="red" mt={2}></Box>
                        </>
                      </InputGroup>
                    </>
                  </ModalBody>
                  <ModalFooter mb={4}>
                    <Button
                      key={`btn${Math.random() * 1000}`}
                      id={modal.web}
                      colorScheme="blue"
                      border="1px"
                      isFullWidth
                      type="submit"
                      _hover={{ bg: "#152aa3" }}
                      disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                    >
                      Submit
                    </Button>
                  </ModalFooter>
                </ModalContent>
              </Modal>

              <SimpleGrid
                columns={{ base: 1, sm: 1, md: 3, xl: 4 }}
                spacing="6"
              >
                <FieldArray name="locations">
                  {() =>
                    formik.values?.locations?.map(
                      (props: any, index: number) => {
                        const { facebookUrl } = props;

                        return (
                          <>
                            <Flex
                              direction="column"
                              alignItems="center"
                              rounded="md"
                              padding="8"
                              position="relative"
                              shadow="base"
                              id={index}
                            >
                              <Box
                                position="absolute"
                                inset="0"
                                height="20"
                                roundedTop="inherit"
                              />
                              <VStack spacing="4" mt={3}>
                                {buttons.map(({ title, id, icon }) => (
                                  <Button
                                    key={id + 1}
                                    id={id}
                                    colorScheme="grayExtend.100"
                                    borderWidth="1px"
                                    borderColor="grayExtend.300"
                                    variant="outline"
                                    p="10px"
                                    borderRadius="4px"
                                    minH="60px"
                                    minW="300px"
                                    onClick={(e) => handleOpenModal(e, index)}
                                    className={
                                      formik.values.locations[index]
                                        .facebookUrl &&
                                      formik.errors &&
                                      formik.errors.locations &&
                                      getIn(
                                        formik.errors,
                                        `locations.${index}.facebookUrl`
                                      ) &&
                                      "success"
                                    }
                                    display="flex"
                                    justifyContent="start"
                                    bg="#f5faff"
                                    fontSize="0.875rem"
                                  >
                                    {title}
                                  </Button>
                                ))}
                              </VStack>
                            </Flex>
                          </>
                        );
                      }
                    )
                  }
                </FieldArray>
              </SimpleGrid>
            </form>
          </Box>
        </FormikProvider>
      </Box>
      {/* end card grid */}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: this works , i was messed with id ,great explonation ,Thank you !

Comment: glad to help you)